Can't install Python Imaging Library "Pillow"
I have tried to install pillow library for my Django project it won't install. I have tried many times there are no specific answer for problem on internet.


First Try

Terminal Input:
(venv) PS C:\Users\Samsung\Desktop\lms-django> pip install pillow

Terminal Output:
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\samsung\desktop\lms\venv\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Samsung\Desktop\lms-django\venv\Scripts\pip.exe" install pillow': The system cannot find the file specified.


Second Try:

Terminal Input:
(venv) PS C:\Users\Samsung\Desktop\lms-django> python3 -m pip install

Terminal Output:
The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
 a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:8
+ python3 <<<<  -m pip install
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


I want to find a way to install the python pillow library.

python -m pip install Pillow also didn't work? or just py. Sometimes windows has problems with environment vars. I like to use Git Bash console when working with python in windows.

Afaik when using venv, the Python executable will be always be python.exe regardless of version. The name won't have a version number in it.

Both of these Outputs indicate that your virtual-environment is either corrupted or was not initialized properly. So, you can try deleting this environment and recreating another one.
Also in Windows, use python instead of python3 unless you have another installation of python2.7

I have deactivated the environment and reactivated. after i tried this command it was a successfully worked.
python -m pip install pillow

Great! @DulangaDasanayake, please accept the answer if it helped
